# Django file upload/download in a social community

Tags: django, file, upload, download

I have a social community built in Django, and i want to add a upload/download/read(documents) feature for users, so that many users can do these operations in the same time.

What do you recommend me?
The standard Django upload/download document feature is ok for that purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's best to delegate those to the static media webserver.  Usually you just generate an empty response wth some headers ('X-Accel-Redirect' on nginx, 'XSendFile' on most others) that specify the path of the file.  This allows you to use Django for the logic but the webserver for the serving itself.